# Live source code appearing different to Visual Studio code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am working on my site in ASP.NET 4.0 In C# And as apart of my assignment it has to validate, now I am using the w3c validator and when I see the source of my site in there, there are parts of Markup that do not display in visual studio 2012 that I need to remove to get my site to validate.  Is there an option I can use to fix this.

Comment: Are you confusing the original markup with the HTML output that is generated?

Comment: Essentially when I view the source code of my site when its live there are parts of markup that I can not see when editing the site in visual studio.  In this instance there is a grid view this some bad attributes that I just can not remove.

Comment: You will find that using controls that abstract a lot of stuff (like GridViews) prevents you from having tight control over the HTML that gets generated. If you want to have tighter control, stick to things that you can easily control the HTML, for example by using a [Repeater control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to build an HTML table. If you need filtering and searching, then use something client side based, such as the [DataTable JavaScript library](https://datatables.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gridview's Mark-up is generated dynamically at run time to view the markup right click the output page and do view source, if you want to edit the gridviews markup in visual studio you need to convert the fields into template fields and that way you can display what you want.

try this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx